# Parsing XML into JSON - trying to replace all "$" key values with regex or stop it all together

Tags: json, node.js, regex, xml

So I have been taking some XML and parsing it through xml2js package to get JSON. The parsing worked fine though I keep getting "$" for the list of attributes. For example:

```
<AddresseeInformation name="SOME COMPANY LTD"></AddresseeInformation>
```

Becomes

```
"AddresseeInformation":[{"$":{"name":"SOME COMPANY LTD"}}]
```

I dont want this as MongoJS is saying that key $ must not start with '$' when I try to upload it to the DB - so I am going to have to change every instance of "$" or figure out how to stop it from happening.

Here is the regex I have tried to change every instance:

```
JSONstring.replace('"$"'/g, '"init"');
          .replace(/"$"/g, '"init"');
          .replace(/'"$"'/g, '"init"');
```

None of that worked - so I am sending it out to you guys - also if anyone knows how to stop the XML attributes being parsed with a key of "$" I would love you forever.

Comment: `var parser = new require('xml2js').Parser({attrkey: 'ATTR'});`?

Comment: Using regex on a JSON string runs a very high risk of breaking the JSON, since regex are not capable of correctly dealing with nested structures like JSON (or XML, HTML). Don't do that. If you want to modify JSON, always parse it into a data structure first, write code that modifies that data structure, and then serialize the result back to JSON. The better option here is to change the key that `xml2js` uses for attributes to something other than the default `'$'`. I recommend `'@'` because that's what XPath would use and - in contrast to a string like `'ATTR'` - can't occur naturally in XML.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js), under "Options", seems to suggest that creating the parser with `new Parser({attrkey:"init"})` does what you want.

For the RegExp solution, the problem is that `$` has a special meaning and you have to escape it: `/"\$"/g`.  (Although technically it should probably be `/"\$"\s*:/g` in case a value happens to be `"$"`.  Or `/(?<!\\)"\$"\s*:/g` if you *really* want to be careful and exclude keys ending in `"$`.  And RegExp probably isn't the best solution anyways.)

Comment: Please do not recommend using regular expressions to work on JSON. Regular expressions are technically incapable of making meaningful changes to JSON.

Comment: @Tomalak 1) I'm not necessarily recommending regular expressions, just saying what's wrong with that particular one; 2) JSON is simple enough that certain searches and changes *can* be made with regular expressions, assuming you're starting with valid, standard-compliant JSON, and that you know some things about what keys it can have (though, granted, the original corrected regular expression may change more than necessary).  Since JSON can't have comments and most characters can't appear outside strings, `"$"` is always going to be a string, and `"$":` is always going to be a key name.